# Using Fermat’s Little Theorem to compute $3^{649} \bmod{85}$

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, cryptography

I am confused about the steps to solve it. I know that $\mbox{gcd}(3,85) = 1$. I got

$$\phi(85) = 85 \left( 1 - \frac15 \right) \left( 1 - \frac{1}{17} \right) = 64$$

and then, by Euler's theorem, $3^{64} \equiv 1 \bmod{85}$. What would be the next step?

Comment: Since $\mathrm{gcd}(3, 85) = 1$, you have that $3^{\varphi(85)} \equiv 1 \pmod{85}$ by Fermat's little theorem. Here $\varphi(n)$ is Euler's totient function, i.e. the number of positive integers less than $n$ that are coprime to $n$.

Comment: What do you know of Fermat's Little Theorem/Eulers Theorem a?  There are a lot of questions about this and the are all much the same..... $3^{\phi(85)}\equiv 1\pmod 85$. so $3^{649}\equiv 3^{649\pmod \phi(85)}\pmod 85$.  And $649\pmod \phi(85)$ is likely to be a small enough number to be handleable.

Comment: @Rushy Actually it is Euler Theorem and not Fermat's Little Theorem (which is for primes).  Minor point.

Comment: The key observation you're missing is that $3^{649}=3^{64\cdot 10+9}=(3^{64})^{10}3^9$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** How does $649$ compare to $64$?

Can you finish?

Comment: I'm a bit confused by what that means?

Comment: @MichaelLuong: Please refer to Troposphere's comment underneath your question.

Comment: but why did we do 3^(649)=3^(64*10+9)=(3^64)^(10)3^(9)?

Comment: Because $3^{64} \equiv 1 \pmod {85}$, which is equivalent to $(3^{64})^{10} \equiv 1 \pmod {85}$.

Comment: that's why we need to solve for 3^(9)mod(85)?

Comment: Yes!  Because the other factor is congruent to $1$ modulo $85$.

Comment: Thank you now I understand

Comment: That's great!  I am glad I was able to help.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\varphi(85)=64$ we have that $3^{649}\equiv 3^{9}\pmod{85}$. Now it is very practical to invoke the Chinese remainder theorem. $85=5\cdot 17$ and $3^9\equiv 3\pmod{5}$ while by taking $p=17$
$$ 3^9 \equiv 3\cdot 3^{\frac{p-1}{2}} \equiv 3\left(\frac{3}{17}\right) \equiv 3\left(\frac{17}{3}\right)\equiv -3\pmod{17} $$
so the wanted remainder is the first element in $\{17k-3\}_{k\geq 1}$ which ends with a $3$ or an $8$, so $14\to 31\to \color{green}{48}$.

Comment: Even more practical is to use the fact that $3^4\equiv -4\bmod 85$.

Answer (score 1):

$649= 10 \times 64 + 9$ so it follows that $$3^{649} = (3^{64})^{10} \times 3^9$$ by standard exponent rules.

So modulo $85$ we get (as the left hand becomes a power of $1$):

$$3^{649} = 3^9 \pmod{85}$$

which will make it easier...

Answer (score 0):

$3^{4}\equiv 1\pmod 5$ and $3^{16}\equiv 1\pmod {17}$ together imply By CRT, that $3^{16}\equiv 1\pmod {85}$ so $3^{649=16\cdot 40+9}\equiv 3^9\cdot {85}$ which you can then easily solve.